# Dissolution of portlandite, calcite/CaCo3 phase and C-S-H due to high pH

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, aqueous-solution, ph, alkali-metals

I would like to ask about the possibility of the partial dissolution, over curing time, of portlandite, CaCo3 and C-S-H phases due to high pH (12.5 - 13) of the lime-clay-water systems (lime-stabilized clay). These phases were already newly formed phases in the lime-stabilized  bentonite formed in the short term (1 day). I noticed a decrease in their amounts over curing time.

Comment: CaCo3 is a hypothetic stoichiometric inter-metallic compound of calcium and cobalt.  // Consistent misuse of proper element symbols is frown upon very much.

Comment: A capital crime!

Comment: To clarify: after 1 day, the compounds were quantified (how?), and cured (how long?). Were new phases (new materials) identified, or were the first very crystalline products growing to amorphous clusters - lower but broader peaks?